# Retain the value in Global filter after refreshing the page in angular2

Tags: angular

I have used a data table and a global filter which filters the data from the data table in angular2.I am performing the following operation.

When I entered some value in the filter, the records are getting filtered. But when I perform some operation(for e.g., approve the record),the page gets refreshed by removing the particular record(as expected) and the filter also gets cleared.But what I want is,the filter should not be cleared and it has to display the records which are previously present(except the deleted record) before performing the action even after performing approve action. I am able to retain the value in filter by using ngModel but the records are not getting filtered.They were getting filtered only after focusing and press enter button or pressing key space or entering some letter.

So could you please help me in filtering the data after refreshing the page

Answer (score 0):

You can use the router query parameters to filter you data

get the filter in your constructor

```
constructor(private router: Router, private route: ActivatedRoute) {
    this.route
     .queryParams
     .subscribe(params => { 
         const filter = params['filter'] || '';
         this.applyFilter(filter);
     });
 }
```

set the filter

```
onFilter(param: string): void {
    this.router.navigate(['mypage'], { queryParams: { filter: param} });
}
```